# ¿Cómo ver la parte de texto que coincide con la búsqueda en python?

Tags: python, regex

Tengo un problema estoy trabajando en un blog, en el cual voy a poner un buscador interno el cual busque en una base de datos la información de las entradas, el código es el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# encoding=utf8
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

import pymongo

inputSearch = raw_input("Ingrese Su Busqueda: ").lower()

conexion =  pymongo.MongoClient()
db = conexion['blog']

palabras = inputSearch.split()

def resultados(palabras):
    coleccion = db['pageContent']
    search = ""
    for palabra in palabras:
        search = search + ".*" + palabra + "" + " "
    get = coleccion.find({"Data": {"$regex": search}}).limit(100)
    return get

resultados = resultados(palabras)
for resultado in resultados:
    print  resultado["url"] + " " + resultado["Data"]
```

Lo que este código hace es buscar en la base de datos las entradas que contienen lo que el usuario busca, y me regresa la url y el contenido de toda la entrada.
Mi intención es que del texto de toda la entrada obtener un fragmento el cual coincida con lo que el usuario, algo parecido a lo que hace google.
por ejemplo si el usuario busca **Expresiones regulares en python** del texto de las entradas que coincidan me devuelva un fragmento como este:

> Al buscar direcciones de correo electrónico, números de teléfono, validar campos de entrada, o una letra mayúscula seguida de dos minúsculas y de 5 dígitos entre 1 y 3; es necesario recurrir a las **Expresiones Regulares**, también conocidas como Patrones. Puedes aprender más **en** el Curso de **Python** y luego ...

*Lo de las palabras en negrita no importa*

```
def obtenerPosiciones(texto #En texto recibe el contenido de cada entrada, busqueda #En busqueda se pasa una lista):
posiciones = []
for palabra in busqueda:
    patron = re.compile(r'\b'+palabra+r'\b')
    s = patron.finditer(texto)
    ubicacion = []
    for elemento in s:
        l = elemento.span()
        ubicacion.append(l)
    posiciones.append(ubicacion)
return posiciones

print obtenerPosiciones(texto, busqueda)
```

Con esta parte de código obtengo las posiciones de cada palabra en todo el texto, el problema es que no encuentro la forma correcta de obtener el fragmento de texto a partir de estas posiciones.
Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ¿Y cuales son las condiciones para definir el fragmento a retornar (aparte de contener las palabras)?¿Cuanta longitud ha de tener el fragmento antes/después de la primera/última coincidencia?¿Si hay una gran distancia entre las palabras buscadas se retorna todo el fragmento aunque sea muy grande?¿O se corta?¿O no es considerada una coincidencia?, etc. Estas reglas son lo importante, obtener la subcadena es trivial, bastaría un simple slicing de acuerdo a los indices que ya tienes.

Comment: @FJSevilla, me has adelantado con los comentarios ;) Creo que hay potencial para una buena pregunta y más interesantes respuestas, el problema es que es demasiado amplia así como está. Agrego mis consultas: ¿Que pasa con las preposiciones? (pueden desvirtuar la búsqueda) ¿Que pasa con las variantes de una palabra? Ej: Expresiones o Expresion.

Comment: Para mi esta pregunta es interesante pero demasiado amplia, le recomendaria a @OrlandoVC que divida su proyecto en pequeñas partes y para cada uno cree una pregunta, primero el caso basico que solo cuente la cantidad de coincidencias, despues añadir otros aspectos del lenguaje, etc.

Comment: una disculpa por no darme a entender bien, me interesa obtener el fragmento de texto que este en un rango de 250 a 350 caracteres, si la distancia esta muy grande que seleccione solo una. espero que darme a entender

Comment: Si no te entendí mal, quieres mostrara un extracto que vaya de 250 a 300 caracteres? imagino que tenga la mayor cantidad de palabras de la búsqueda. es así?

Comment: si, es asi, algo parecido a los que hacen los buscadores internos de los blogs.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que mi recomendación principal sería que evites implementarlo por tu cuenta. Un buscador es algo bastante [complicado](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38324/how-would-you-implement-google-search) de implementar y obtener algo con un mínimo de funcionalidad y calidad será un trabajo tedioso.

Una alternativa sería delegar las búsquedas a google. Podrías utilizar el [Motor de búsqueda personalizado de Google](https://cse.google.es/cse/) y así no reinventar la rueda :)

Como puedes ver, incluso en wordpress.org utilizan esto último. https://wordpress.org/search/mi%20busqueda

Sí aún así pretendes implementar algo básico por tu cuenta, como punto de partida te recomendaría refinar tu expresión regular que utilizas en `coleccion.find`

Tal cual la tienes, estás uniendo todas las palabras con `.*` lo cual no es óptimo porque estás forzando a que aparezcan en ese orden concreto y otros órdenes no serían válidos.

Por ejemplo, dadas las palabras `coche` y `amarillo`. Tú las estás uniendo así: `coche.*amarillo`, lo cual encontraría el texto `tengo un coche amarillo` pero no el texto `de color amarillo es mi coche`

Podrías unir las palabras así: `(?:\b(?:palabra1|palabra2|palabra3)\b)`

La expresión regular explicada:

```
(?:        # inicio de grupo
    \b     # límite de palabra
    (?:    # grupo con las opciones para las palabras
         palabra1|
         palabra2|
         palabra3
    )
    \b    # Límite de palabra
)
```

Así encontrarías todas las palabras y además funcionaría si no aparecen todas.

Después con todo el texto recuperado deberías ir buscando el trozo de 250 a 350 caracteres con el número más alto de palabras.

Una forma (seguramente poco eficiente) sería recorrer el resultado en trozos de 250 y para cada trozo acumular la cantidad de palabras encontradas (podría ser un diccionario con clave = posición del trozo y valor = número de palabras encontradas).

Después, finalmente devolver el trozo con más palabras encontradas.

También podrías considerar descartar algunas palabras como preposiciones y artículos.